# xamarin forms - picker UI reloading after selecting from picker

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

Xamarin forms - creating an app with a listView and picker as a selection for quantity..for testing I have added 3 ProductModel records.

On screen, for no apparent reason, happening sometimes, not always...when the second or third productModel is selected from the listview, the picker popUp appears....the user picks a number from the picker. when they select the number, the picker closes and re-opens.

Been trying to find exact use case for this happening but cant see...only know that it never happens on the first record. Only second and third.

Thanks

```
    //Product Model
public class ProductModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 private int _ProductId;
        private string _ProductName;
        private string _Quantity;
        private string tempQuantity = "-1";

        //Constructor
        public ProductModel()
        {
            //Subscription
            this.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
        }

 [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ProductId
        {
            get { return _ProductId; }
            set
            {
                if (_ProductId == value) return;
                _ProductId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        //Properties
        public string Quantity
        {
            get {
                return _Quantity;
            }
            set
            {
                _Quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

  public string ProductName
        {
            get { return _ProductName; }
            set
            {
                _ProductName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

 private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Quantity))
            {
                //test quantity amount
            }
        }

        // [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}


//ProductPageViewModel
public class ProductPageViewModel : BindableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> WineList { get; set; }

        public ProductPageViewModel()
        {
  WineList = new ObservableCollection<ProductModel>();
            WineList.Add(new ProductModel
            {
                ProductId = 1,
                ProductName = "Wine 101",//,
                Quantity = "0"
            });
            WineList.Add(new ProductModel
            {
                ProductId = 2,
                ProductName = "Wine 102",//,
                Quantity = "0"
            });
            WineList.Add(new ProductModel
            {
                ProductId = 3,
                ProductName = "Wine 103",//,
                Quantity = "0"
            });
}

}

//ProductPage.xaml
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <ListView  x:Name="producttablelist" IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding WineList}" HeightRequest="1500">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="120" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Start"></Label>

                                    <Picker Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start"  SelectedIndex="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <Picker.Items>
                                            <x:String>0</x:String>
                                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                                            <x:String>3</x:String>
                                            <x:String>4</x:String>
                                            <x:String>5</x:String>
                                            <x:String>6</x:String>
                                        </Picker.Items>
                                    </Picker>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
       
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


//ProductPage.xaml.cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductPageViewModel productPage_ViewModal;
  public ProductPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            productPage_ViewModal = new ProductPageViewModel();
            BindingContext = productPage_ViewModal;
        }
}
```

Comment: I test with your codes above,but could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: It is unclear from your question & code what is happening. I suggest you recreate the issue in a blank project and then upload to GitHub for people to run and have a look at